# BottomSheetDialog Pop Up

Tags: java, android

So what I'm trying to do is a music app.
I want to have a bottomsheetdialog that only opens in the homepage when there's a song playing and i can press pause through that bottomsheetdialog. Spotify would be a great example. Is there any example code that I can refer to? I am doing this on Android Studio Java.

Comment: `JavaScript !== Java`

Comment: You're asking for help with three separate things, none of them very specific. Do you need help with getting a Bottom Sheet Dialog to appear? Or with getting a dialog to appear automatically when some other condition is true, i.e., music is playing? Or presenting a pause button in a Bottom Sheet Dialog? Or getting a pause button to pause your music when presented in a Bottom Sheet Dialog?

Comment: Getting the bottom sheet dialog to appear automatically when the music is playing. (: Sry first time asking a qns.